# Mock set an attribute that doesn't have a set

Tags: c#, mocking

Hi everyone smarter than me :-) I have another application which requires generation of an abstract class, and due to testing purposes is quite difficult to debug. therefor i created a wrapper and can define my abstract classes in visual Studio now (instead of native application)

However, the native application is expecting public abstract [obj type] values with only a get; method, and if i put in a set;, the application will bomb. Is there any way to set a field using Reflection or Mock to this field, and NOT have the set method?

```
//simplified class
public abstract class GetEUserAndDetails : [app specific interfaces]
{
      public abstract Metastorm.Runtime.Types.Text paramFullNameLike
      {
            get;
            set; //note: If i have this here, it will fail in Metastorm
      }
      public System.Data.DataSet Read()
      {
            //do something
      }
}
```

and in Main() it's a c# winform, i have

```
Mock<Metastorm.Runtime.Models.MySampleProject.GetEUserAndDetails> mockMyBO = new Mock<Metastorm.Runtime.Models.MySampleProject.GetEUserAndDetails>() { CallBase = true };

//using reflection
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in mockMyBO.Object.GetType().GetProperties())
{ 
     //simplified again, another form getting parameters and such
     pi.SetValue(mockMyBO.Object, form.myTextParam, null);
}
```

If I don't have the set method, the pi.SetValue() line will fail, but if i do, it will fail in the native app. (note: i'm using the same test harness to test all sorts of abstract classes that will all implement the Read() method and need to test that it is pulling the correct data back, but the parameters will be different for each class.

Sorry if my code is bad i couldn't get it to format properly, and also please bear with me if i used the wrong terms. I'm not an expert by any means, just enough to be dangerous. I am just living with leaving the set; line for the moment and manually removing it before copy/pasting into the main application, but would like to find another way to do this for when there are many params.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your scenario correctly, you actually want to test the code in the abstract class, and not mock it.

With that in mind, I think the easiest approach in this case is simply to create a subclass within your test, that will inherit from your base class, and implement whatever is necessary for you to be able to test the base class.

Such as:

```
public class GetUserAndDetailsImplementation : GetEUserAndDetails 
{
    private Metastorm.Runtime.Types.Text _paramFullNameLike;

    public override Metastorm.Runtime.Types.Text paramFullNameLike
    {
        get { return _paramFullNameLike; }
    }

    public void SetParamFullNameLike(Metastorm.Runtime.Types.Text text)
    {
        _paramFullNameLike = text;
    }
}
```

And you can use that class as entry point for your testing.

Now if you really want to use a mock, have you tried the following?

```
var mock = new Mock<GetEUserAndDetails> { CallBase = true };
mock.SetupGet(x => x.paramFullNameLike).Returns(<some value>);
```

Comment: Yes I am trying to test the class. However, I am going to be writing about 30 of these classes over the next week, And I don't want to have to create a subclass of each abstract class and override the attributes. That will take quite a bit of time, and then wouldn't allow me to re-use my "main" application code because it would have to be changed per class.

As it stands now, i can just change Mock<TypeA> to Mock<TypeB> and the code does exactly what i need to do.

Does that clarify?

Comment: I see. I just added a few comments in my answer.

Comment: I posted before you edited your comment. As for doing
    mock.SetupGet(x => x.paramFullNameLike).Returns(<some value>);
no i have not used that. I am using reflection to set the values because i don't want to have to write code for each different attribute that will be in my class. each class will have it's own different attributes that need to be set, hence the use of reflection.

Comment: I don't think you actually need "Set" implemented, since the mock will handle that for you when you define what it should return. Now, if you want something automated, maybe you can try using reflection to Setup the mock as I did above, calling the extension methods. However, that may make your test a bit complex and not too clear about what it's doing.

Comment: I have a code which will find all the properties that are named "param" and then prompt for a replacement value, and then set the value using reflection. The issue is that if i don't have a set; then the code to set the value will fail. Maybe i mislabeled this question and it should be more related to reflection vs Mock. again, i'm not an expert in coding.